# case when...then 1 else 0

Tags: sql

I just learn SQL for one month and have a question that what does it mean about 1 and 0 in the subquery 'case when...then 1 else 0'?
I have google for similar questions, and it says 1 and 0 just means plus 1 and plus 0.
But I can't understand what it means.
Does it mean that the result that code runs will be plus one or plus zero?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Those are numbers.  What about them do you not understand?

Comment: Post your query please

Comment: It's probably intended to represent 1 (true) and 0 (false) although that's likely just by convention. Without more of the query it's difficult to speculate. In fact what you're calling a "subquery" may just be an "expression".

Answer (score 0):

"Case when"  can be used for modifying result values, also for categorising.

Example: lets say we have a table with percent values (0-100), and we want to categorise as PASS when the value is > 70%, else as FAIL:

```
select case when percentage > 70 then "PASS" else "FAIL" end from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really, this means that the result of the query will be one or zero.

Not some expression of plus one or plus zero, but just one or zero. As a simple number.

Example:

We want to indicate that everyone whose age is greater than 18 belongs to the category of people number 1, and those whose age is less than 18 belongs to the category of people number 0.

Query:

```
SELECT [Name],
    CASE
    WHEN [Age] >= 18 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END AS [AgeType];
```

For the data:

```
Name|Age
Nick|20
Mark|17
Bob |18
```

The result will be:

```
Name|AgeType
Nick|1
Mark|0
Bob |1
```